# Updating version of multiple components using 1 file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution with many components and each component has its own version file (AssemblyInfo.cs).  Currently each file as the standard structure:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

I would like to use the file version as the component version and keep that independent but I would like to have the "Product Version" be the same for all the components. 
I would like to do that by having a file at the solution level that is used by all the projects to get that version embedded.

Any suggestions
Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply put `AssemblyVersion` in a file shared by all projects, and `AssemblyFileVersion` - in the project-local file.

Or do I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I use a similar approach. Note that to "share" a file among projects, do an `Add Existing Item`, browse to the file, and then select `Add As Link` from the little arrow on the right side of the button.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but I get the error: 
AssemblyVersion no found

Comment: I got it to compile but it is not showing the new version. I moved the AssemblyVersion to a new file and added a link but the assemblies shows the File version for both File and Product.

Comment: I just found this comment somewhere else:
If you're not signing your assemblies, assembly version numbers don't
matter to the compiler, they're ignored. 
Is that what I am seeing here?

Comment: Yes, it is what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way we do it. We have a solution wide file defining a global  assemblyVersion and include by link in each subproject and a project file defining assemblyFileVersion in each project.

If you want to automatically update the version you could use '1.0.*' syntax.